# What is the meaning of "..." in modern English?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have read the [Linguistics FAQ](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1) however considering I am new here I thought it would be more appropriate to ask first in the meta:

Would a question regarding the meaning, translation and/or origin of a phrase or word from a language the user does not know into English be suitable for Linguistics SE?

If so, would the original language the phrase is in be required for tagging?

Comment: Can you write the title the question would have? Because right now it looks like a proof-reading for a translation question and that would be off topic (if asked bluntly like this).

Comment: @Alenanno Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the core of the question is that one, I'm afraid it'd be off topic. There is nothing Linguistic-ish in it, at least apparently.

You could ask on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but I advise you to search a lot in dictionaries and other common sources, otherwise your question is likely to get closed.

If I have misunderstood the intent of your question, feel free to comment! :)

By the way, thanks for asking before posting, I appreciate that.

Comment: I am aware of the English Language SE, but I was also thinking the possibility of non-English phrases, which would clearly not belong there either. The reason behind my curiosity is due to the fact that many online dictionaries and translator fail to bring results in the aforementioned case.