# Nomination for reopening: another etymology question which had a part about current meaning (which I dropped)

Tags: discussion, off-topic-questions

When I mentioned it as an inconsistency [here](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/is-this-question-about-etymology-and-meaning-really-off-topic), I was almost expecting it would result it [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/what-is-the-etymology-of-sicilian-vanedda) being closed. However, I now edited it to drop the concern about current meaning (except as an end to the evolution of the meaning through the ages) and about the usage in the song. That part is still present, but the Edit at the end says to ignore it.

If etymology questions are OT here, where can I ask them? I don't know of any SE site more fit for etymology questions than this one…

So: could this question be reopened now that the meaning part has been (almost entirely) dropped and (almost) only the etymology part remains?

(Also, is there a "Nominations for reopening" thread where I could post these issues? I remember there being one on some other SE site…)

Comment: Lots of interesting questions don't have a home in the Stack Exchange network. General etymology questions are some of those.

Comment: @MickG I've left Quora for my own reasons, but given the... ethos of Stack Exchange with regard to question scope, try Quora too.