# Good examples of etymology questions

Tags: discussion, scope, etymology

I've [said before](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1756/2555) that etymology has a tricky relationship with linguistics:

> Linguistics is the study of language systems. Etymology questions belong here when they're asking about systematic issues. This could involve sound system changes. It could be about languages which have borrowed wholesale and systematically from another language. And questions on grammatical morphology are almost always on topic. But non systematic arbitrary borrowings or meaning changes don't really belong here.

We see lots of poor etymology questions. But as [we continue to discuss this site's guidelines for etymology questions](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1838/2555) I thought it would help to identify some *good* examples, because this will help us see what works.

So feel free to reply and start your own list of etymology questions you think are really good. You don't need to try to be objective - let your personal subjective impressions be recorded, so that we can capture our intuitions and then better understand what we think makes good etymology questions good.

Comment: But why do you think that [simple vote count](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology?sort=votes) is not sufficient?

Comment: @byte Because clearly more people like the terrible questions than I want. And sometimes that's influenced by the HNQ list.

Answer (score 3):

Here are mine. I'll add to it as I come across more.

- [Relations between 'knee' and 'generation'](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31345/2555)
- [Are any of the Old Chinese reconstructions for「能」plausible descendants of Proto-Sino-Tibetan /*dɣwjəm/?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31120/2555)

Answer (score 0):

This is my list of okay etymology questions:

- [Which of 可爱/可愛い was exported to the other between Chinese and Japanese?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20049/which-of-%E5%8F%AF%E7%88%B1-%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84-was-exported-to-the-other-between-chinese-and-japanese)
- [How did Norwegian "huske" derive from ON "hugsa"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/how-did-norwegian-huske-derive-from-on-hugsa)